# Can anyone tell me what this font is or which is similar?

Tags: font-identification

Can anyone tell me what this font is or which is similar?

[image: font]

Comment: Mandatory comment we leave in all font-identification questions: Have you tried cleaning the background and using http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont ?

Answer (score 3):

Adding to [the answer given by Ilan](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/28051/11973):

- The "variation" Ilan mentions really is **Menlo Bold** (which - as I just realized *after* writing up all of this :/ - he wanted to fix this in [this edit to his answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/revisions/28051/2), but apparently something went wrong).
- Furthermore, as [Menlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menlo_%28typeface%29) is based upon [Bitstream Vera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstream_Vera) Sans Mono and [Deja Vu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_fonts) Sans Mono, let us take a look those, too:

[image: Original screenshot in comparison to Menlo Bold, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono Bold and DejaVu Sans Mono Bold]

*Red: [Menlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menlo_%28typeface%29) Bold; Cyan: [Bitstream Vera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstream_Vera) Sans Mono Bold; Green: [DejaVu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_fonts) Sans Mono Bold

- all at 50pt, set in [Adobe Illustrator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator) on Mac OS X*

While the regular cuts of Menlo and DejaVu Sans Mono have a few more or less subtle differences (reference the screenshot and links below the horizontal rule), I could not make out any differences regarding the bold cuts and your reference text (I did not compare the whole character set).

- If your reference image is from a website, you could use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) or [Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg589507%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find out which font is used via the "Inspect Element" tool and looking at the `font-family` property in the "Computed Style"-panel.
  [As Yisela already pointed out](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28047/can-anyone-tell-me-what-this-font-is-or-which-is-similar#comment36928_28049), a quicker way is "[WhatFont](http://chengyinliu.com/whatfont.html)", a tool available as a bookmarklet and extension for Chrome and Safari.
- If your reference is a high resolution image or a PDF with fonts converted to paths, you could compare the fonts yourself; ruling out Menlo should be rather easy if your source contains one of the characters where the differences are rather obvious - that is if you have access to Menlo: I ([as others](https://superuser.com/questions/59456/any-good-way-to-get-the-new-menlo-font-on-windows)) could not find a download link ([at least not to the bold cut](https://superuser.com/a/697515)) - it is however shipping with [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X) since [Snow Leopard (10.6)](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2009/06/font-changes-coming-to-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/).
- If your reference is a PDF with fonts embedded (though I doubt that), you can view a list of all fonts in [Adobe Acrobat/Reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Acrobat) via `File → Properties → Fonts`.

Citing the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_fonts), DejaVu was created to "provide a wider range of characters... while maintaining the original look and feel through the process of collaborative development", so as far as I understand there [should not be a difference regarding letter forms](http://fnurl.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/dvsb.gif) (image from [here](http://blog.fnurl.se/2011/06/22/comparison-bitstream-vs-dejavu-vs-menlo/)) in regards to Bitstream Vera.

A derivative of Menlo named ["Meslo"](https://github.com/andreberg/Meslo-Font) which offers increased vertical line spacing and changes the alignment of the asterisk is available at [github](https://github.com/andreberg/Meslo-Font)  (and discussed [here](http://mir.aculo.us/2010/10/12/the-long-search-for-a-terminal-font-is-over/) and [here](http://collindonnell.com/2013/12/29/meslo-font/)).

---

Here's a visual comparison of Menlo *Regular* and DejaVu Sans Mono *Book* (as found [here](http://typophile.com/node/58625#comment-351070)):

[image]

Even more detailed comparisons (also to Bitstream Vera Sans Mono) can be found [here](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2009/10/the-compleat-menlovera-sans-comparison/), [here](http://blog.fnurl.se/2011/06/22/comparison-bitstream-vs-dejavu-vs-menlo/) and [here](http://www.expandrive.com/menlo-vera-sans-mono-comparison).

Comment: Excellent answer! Welcome to GD.SE :)

Answer (score 2):

The font is variation of **Menlo Regular Font**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If this is on the web somewhere as copy (as opposed to in an image) you can use this handy tool:

[FOUNT](http://fount.artequalswork.com/)

It is a bookmarklet that you drag to your browser and it scan the dom for the font-family tags and help you identify a font.

This is a must have for anyone who wants to know **on the fly** what a page uses for fonts. A follow up tool would be the commented "[What The Font](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)" location from above.

Comment: Interesting! For web I use a chrome extension called [**WhatFont**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en). Although I'm not sure if the pic the OP posted is web, it looks like a JPG.

Comment: Agreed. The image looks...like an image hahah. but it is also hard to tell now with all of the z-index and css styling going on out there.